# How to handle Menus with WinForms, MVP and Commands

Tags: winforms, command, mvp, command-pattern

I have a WinForm based solution, being implemented using MVP.

We have Menus which should use a Command per Menu and there are other mechanism to invoke commands as well.

Now.. from a concrete implementation of the View, view elements (menus, buttons etc) are bound to Commands using a CommandBinder.

My question here is How should Presenter be linked to Commands?

Should each command call Presenter's respective function?
Should each Presenter own the commands and be called from there?

Comment: Did you have a look at this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188928.aspx

Comment: I am comfortable with Commands and Forms and Management of commands. I wanted to know, Shall the form events directly invoke the commands or all this should happen through a Presenter and in which case how all of them fit together.